# AS3 sort on Vector doesn't behave as expected

Tags: actionscript-3, sorting, vector

I have a vector of fixed length 9 with some objects. each object has a variable value:Point and the vector shall be sorted such that objects with a higher value.x appear first - and if theyr value.x is the same, then the one with the smaller value.y shall be first.

this is my compare function:

```
    private function cmpr(h1:HelpObj, h2:HelpObj):Number{ 
        var res:Number;
        if(h1.value.x==h2.value.x){
            res = h1.value.y-h2.value.y;
            return res;
        }
        else{
            res = h2.value.x-h1.value.x;
            return res;
        }
    }
```

but as you can see on this screenshot, the resulting order is not what it's supposed to be:

[image: problem]

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compare function recieves arguments `a` and `b`.

It must return

- -1 if `a` has to be placed before `b`
- 0 if positions of `b` and `a` are equal
- 1 if `a` has to be placed after `b`

You are returning  whatever values, not just those three listed, which is why order gets messed up.

Compare the results in example below.

```
var test:Vector.<Number>;

// returning whatever the difference is
var sortMethod1:Function = function (a:Number, b:Number) : Number
{
    var value:Number = a-b;
    trace(a+"\t"+b +"\t= "+ value);
    return value;
}

// returning -1, 0, 1
var sortMethod2:Function = function (a:Number, b:Number) : int
{
    var result:int;
    if (a < b) {
        result = -1;
    } else if (a > b) {
        result =  1;    
    } else {
        result 0;
    }
    trace(a+"\t"+b +"\t: "+ result);
    return result;
}

test = new <Number>[1.2,1.1,1.4,1.5,0];
trace("BEFORE", test);
test.sort(sortMethod1);
trace("AFTER1", test);

trace("--");

test = new <Number>[1.2,1.1,1.4,1.5,0];
trace("BEFORE", test);
test.sort(sortMethod2);
trace("AFTER2", test);

/*
Trace output:

BEFORE 1.2,1.1,1.4,1.5,0
1.1 1.4 = -0.2999999999999998
1.2 1.4 = -0.19999999999999996
1.5 1.4 = 0.10000000000000009
0   1.4 = -1.4
0   1.4 = -1.4
1.1 1.2 = -0.09999999999999987
0   1.2 = -1.2
1.5 1.2 = 0.30000000000000004
1.5 1.2 = 0.30000000000000004
0   1.2 = -1.2
0   1.1 = -1.1
AFTER1 0,1.1,1.2,1.5,1.4
--
BEFORE 1.2,1.1,1.4,1.5,0
1.1 1.4 : -1
1.2 1.4 : -1
1.5 1.4 : 1
0   1.4 : -1
1.5 1.4 : 1
0   1.4 : -1
0   1.1 : -1
1.1 1.2 : -1
AFTER2 0,1.1,1.2,1.4,1.5
*/
```

**EDIT** In your case that would be the following:

```
private function cmpr(h1:HelpObj, h2:HelpObj):int
{ 
    var hx1:Number = h1.value.x;
    var hx2:Number = h2.value.x;
    if (hx1 < hx2) {       
        return -1;
    }
    if (hx1 > hx2) {       
        return 1;
    }
    var hy1:Number = h1.value.y;
    var hy2:Number = h2.value.y;
    if (hy1 < hy2) {       
        return -1;
    }
    if (hy1 > hy2) {       
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: but the AS3 help states: `The method takes one parameter. The parameter is one of the following:

a function that takes two arguments of the base type (T) of the Vector and returns a Number:
function compare(x:T, y:T):Number {}
The logic of the function is that, given two elements x and y, the function returns one of the following three values:

a negative number, if x should appear before y in the sorted sequence
0, if x equals y
a positive number, if x should appear after y in the sorted sequence`

Comment: @Nox is correct, you have to return -1, 0 or 1 anything else will mess things up, disregarding what the docs say. This is a small test i made a while back: http://wonderfl.net/c/rK5r

Comment: I'm not quite sure of where are they wrong in their own documentation, but that's clearly so. I've edited my first example so you can see the difference in quick sort steps.

Comment: My guess is that some internal type conversion occurs in quick sort algorithm between Number and int.

Comment: @Mat - What documentation are you quoting?  The AS3 Dev Guide states -1, 0, 1 as the return values for custom compare functions. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ee5.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fa4

Comment: @merv: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html#sort()

Comment: i'm just wondering, whether it is documentation that is foul, or they really mean it...

Answer (score 5):

Have same problem.
Vector.sort() function has a bug.
If you working with float numbers you should not return small numbers like -0.0034
so...

```
someSortFunc( a:SomeObject , b:SomeObject ):Number
{
  return a.val - b.val; //unexpected results
}

someSortFunc( a:SomeObject , b:SomeObject ):Number
{
  return 1000 * ( a.val - b.val ); //correct results
}
```

so better use -1, 1 or 0 :)